# how to handle onclick event of button inside popup window in android

Tags: android

In my application, I have a button initially on the screen, and in `onclick` of the button, a popup window should open. In the popup window, I have an imagebutton, and `onclick` of this button, I want to start an activity. The popup window opens, but I don't understand how to handle the `onclick` of the imagebutton inside the popup window.

In main.xml, I have a button, and in popup_example.xml, I have an imagebutton.

My Java code is as follows:

```
final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
final Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_example,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.layout.main)));
        pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.LEFT,0,0);
        pw.update(8,-70,150,270);

        //if onclick written here, it gives null pointer exception.
        ImageButton img=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home);
        img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent.....
            }
        });

        //if onclick is written here it gives runtime exception.
    });
```

and I have two xml layouts.........

1. main.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:orientation="vertical" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

       <ImageButton 
           android:id="@+id/btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/ghj" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. popup_example.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:orientation="vertical" 
       android:padding="10dip" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:background="#8E2323"> 

      <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
           android:orientation="vertical" 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:padding="5px">

           <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
               android:orientation="vertical" 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:padding="5px"
               android:background="#000000">

               <ImageButton android:id="@+id/home"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/vitalss"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#8E2323"/>                 
           </TableLayout>
       </TableLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Answer (score 18):

You have to find the button into the Popup view:

```
View pview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_example,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.layout.main));
PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(pview);
            pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.LEFT,0,0);
            pw.update(8,-70,150,270);

              //if onclick written here, it gives null pointer exception.
            ImageButton img=(ImageButton)pview.findViewById(R.id.home);
            img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent.....
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

In main activity button onClick you can use:

```
    popupWindow.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.buttonInPopup).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will not give error in Inflater and work properly:

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();


      View pview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_example,    (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.layout.main));
       PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(pview);
        pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.LEFT,0,0);
        pw.update(8,-70,150,270);

          //if onclick written here, it gives null pointer exception.
        ImageButton img=(ImageButton)pview.findViewById(R.id.home);
        img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent.....
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

best solution :)
Pass onCclickMethod from xml

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/save_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            **android:onClick="onClick"**
            android:contentDescription="@string/save"
            android:src="@drawable/save" />
```

it wroked from me..