# Github - Click event is not working from popover view

Tags: android, popover

I am using below example for `popover` view.  [Popover Exmaple - lupidan/PopoverView](https://github.com/lupidan/PopoverView)

I have 3-4 button in `popover` view.  I want to implement click event on `button` but I am not able to find out how to implement it.

**popover_showed_view.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please refer this question : [Handle onclick event of button inside popup window in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997338/how-to-handle-onclick-event-of-button-inside-popup-window-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with switch

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id. button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id. button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id. button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) {
        >perform action  on click
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button1 : {
            >/Your Action
            }
             case R.id.button2 : {
                >Your Action
            }
  case R.id.button3 : {
            >Your Action
            }
}
```